# Xorg open two windows in full screen

Tags: window, x11, archlinux, xorg, window-managers

I would like to open two windows (one per display) in full screen without any controls and bars. I'm using matchbox to do that, which would be ok except one thing. Windows open stretch in full screen in two monitors as it would be one.

I'm using this `.xinitrc` file to control Xorg.

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto --pos 0x1080 --output HDMI1 --auto --pos 0x0
xset s off
xset -dpms
matchbox-window-manager &
electron ./window1
electron ./window2
```

I could change window manager if it only could run application with kiosk restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-use_dialog_mode=free`

```bash
# set window one below another
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --below DP1
matchbox-window-manager -use_dialog_mode=free &
# BONUS: touchscreen cover only area of HDMI1
xinput map-to-output 11 HDMI1
```